# Semicolon gets appended on href URL by using Url.Action (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

This is a snippet of my View getItems.cshtml

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    @{int index = 1;}
    @foreach (var o in ViewBag.CountryList)
    {
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Details", "countries", new { id = index} );">@o</a></li>
                index++;
    }
</ul>
```

The dropdown works as expected but the problem is the **href**

**Expected : countries/Details/id**

**Actual: countries/Details/id;**

Where is the semicolon getting appended from?

How do I remove the semicolon?

Comment: index} );" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo have semicolon  in the tag `new { id = index} );`. please remove it